# Call AuthenticationStateProvider outside page

Tags: authentication, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm writing some kind of control panel for some application. I have a web browser, a Blazer server, and a client. When the user enters the panel, it creates a TcpListener to connect the client. And I have a problem with client authentication .I use the default "RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider" and I want to call it when connecting to the server via TcpListener. What parameters should I send to `RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider` to access the `GetAuthenticationStateAsync` call?